# How to connect using Docker published ports? Not working after upgrade

Tags: docker

Before upgrading my system, I was able to successfully connect to mongo running in a docker container using published ports. After upgrading, as shown in Case #1 connecting via published ports no longer work for me.

Case #1

```
 ~  docker run --rm -d -p 27017:27017 mongo:3.6
2594b7e5cbf481526589d221361c853338ff55ecb32d9e02eae17383960e971a
 ~  docker ps                                  
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                      NAMES
2594b7e5cbf4   mongo:3.6   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   dazzling_fermat
```

```
Robo3T Logs
Cannot connect to the MongoDB at localhost:27017.
Error:
Network is unreachable. Reason: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host 'localhost:27017'
```

```
 ~  sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN      
...
docker-pr 263637            root    4u  IPv4 3723123      0t0  TCP *:27017 (LISTEN)

 ✘  ~  sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Now I can only connect using the host networking stack.

Case #2

```
 ~  docker run --rm -d --network=host mongo:3.6
39929a8d50cc8554d256f7516d039621cd22ed8be86680ac0e1400809464b619
 ~  docker ps                                  
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
39929a8d50cc   mongo:3.6   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds             admiring_grothendieck
```

```
Robo3T Logs
4:13:20 PM  Info: Connecting to localhost:27017...
4:13:20 PM  Info: Establish connection successful. Connection: localhost
```

Pre-upgrade:
Linux Mint 19 - Tricia,
Docker version was 19.xx something I believe.

Post Upgrade:

```
~  lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 20
Release:    20
Codename:   ulyana
 ~  docker --version                                   
Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu1~20.04.1
```

I verified there are no running firewalls (UFD, etc), I can connect from container to container when specifying a private docker network for both the server and client. What am I missing? How can I connect using published ports again? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Docker on Linux generally uses the host's DNS and [modifies your `iptables` to provide the connectivity between the host and container](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/). If there's a problem with connectivity, in your case the most likely culprits are (in order of likelihood):

- DNS entry missing for `localhost` or wrong IP version target. Try using `127.0.0.1` or `::1` as the hostname instead.
- `iptables` rules are missing. Check the earlier link in my response for remediations and flags that can affect this.
- The container might actually have issues starting up. Check the output of `docker log <container_id>` for errors after you start it. I would say this option is unlikely as things work under host network but don't discount this possibility too quickly.